# Unable to retrieve data from Macro Trends using selenium and read_html to create a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm want to import data from macro trends into pandas data frame. From looking at the page source of the website it appears that data is in a jqxgrid.

I have tried using pandas/beautiful soup with the read_html function and no table was found. I am currently trying to use selenium to extract the data. I was hoping that if I could move the horizontal scroll bar table jqxgrid would be loaded and able to be extracted. However, that did not work.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.execute_script("window.location = 'http://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/AMZN/amazon/income-statement?freq=Q';")
driver.implicitly_wait(2)


grid = driver.find_element_by_id('jqxgrid')
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 600);")
scrollbar = driver.find_element_by_id('jqxScrollThumbhorizontalScrollBarjqxgrid')

time.sleep(1)

actions = ActionChains(driver)
time.sleep(1)

for i in range(1,6):
    actions.drag_and_drop_by_offset(scrollbar,i*70,0).perform()
    time.sleep(1)

pd.read_html(grid.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

Error I get is:

> ValueError: No tables found

I would expect table data from "http://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/AMZN/amazon/income-statement?freq=Q" to be imported into a data frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative that's quicker than selenium which has the headers as shown on page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import json
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/AMZN/amazon/income-statement?freq=Q')
p = re.compile(r' var originalData = (.*?);\r\n\r\n\r',re.DOTALL)
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
headers = list(data[0].keys())
headers.remove('popup_icon')
result = []

for row in data:
    soup = bs(row['field_name'])
    field_name = soup.select_one('a, span').text
    fields = list(row.values())[2:]
    fields.insert(0, field_name)
    result.append(fields)

pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None)
df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns = headers)
print(df.head())
```

---

[image]

Comment: Can you explain p = re.compile(r' var originalData = (.*?);\r\n\r\n\r',re.DOTALL)
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])```

Comment: it defines the regex pattern to match on in the response text. Explanation above. p.findall.text)[0] returns the first match for that pattern which is a string which can be loaded with json library to give json object.

Comment: OK, I'll look regex syntax. Probably a silly question, but how do you know exactly how many "\r\n\r\n\r " to use? Is it from the page source or elsewhere?

Comment: I started with a general regex I thought would work from inspecting the javascript source (the json like javascript object). I tweaked the regex until it brought back the json string I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the data is not in a table but 'div' elements. I'm not an expert on pandas but you can do it with BeautifulSoup.

Insert the line after your outher imports

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

then change your last line for:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(grid.get_attribute('outerHTML'), "html.parser")
divList = soup.findAll('div', {'role': 'row'})
data = [[x.text for x in div.findChildren('div', recursive=False)] for div in divList]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(df)
```

This finds all the 'div' elements with the attribute 'row'. Then reads the text elements for each div it finds under the 'div' elements with the attribute 'row' but only descends one level as some have multiple 'div' elements.

Output:

```
                                     0  1       2       3       4       5   \
0                               Revenue     $4,135  $5,672  $3,262  $2,886   
1                    Cost Of Goods Sold     $3,179  $4,501  $2,500  $2,185   
2                          Gross Profit       $956  $1,171    $762    $701   
3     Research And Development Expenses       $234    $222    $209    $201   
4                         SG&A Expenses       $518    $675    $427    $381   
5    Other Operating Income Or Expenses        $-6     $-3     $-3     $-3   
...
        6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13      14  
0   $3,015  $3,986  $2,307  $2,139  $2,279  $2,977  $1,858  $1,753  $1,902  
1   $2,296  $3,135  $1,758  $1,630  $1,732  $2,309  $1,395  $1,303  $1,444  
2     $719    $851    $549    $509    $547    $668    $463    $450    $458  
3     $186    $177    $172    $167    $146    $132    $121    $106     $92  
4     $388    $476    $335    $292    $292    $367    $247    $238    $257  
5        -     $-2     $-2     $-3     $-3     $-4    $-40     $-2     $-1  
...
```

However as you scroll across the page the items on the left are removed from the page source so that not all the data is scraped.

Updated in response to comment.
To set the column headers use:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.execute_script(
    "window.location = 'http://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/AMZN/amazon/income-statement?freq=Q';")
driver.implicitly_wait(2)

grid = driver.find_element_by_id('wrapperjqxgrid')
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 600);")
scrollbar = driver.find_element_by_id('jqxScrollThumbhorizontalScrollBarjqxgrid')

time.sleep(1)

actions = ActionChains(driver)
time.sleep(1)

for i in range(1, 6):
    actions.drag_and_drop_by_offset(scrollbar, i * 70, 0).perform()
    time.sleep(1)


soup = BeautifulSoup(grid.get_attribute('outerHTML'), "html.parser")
headersList = soup.findAll('div', {'role': 'columnheader'})
col_names=[h.text for h in headersList]
divList = soup.findAll('div', {'role': 'row'})
data = [[x.text for x in div.findChildren('div', recursive=False)] for div in divList]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_names)
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
   Quarterly Data | Millions of US $ except per share data   2008-03-31  \
0                                             Revenue            $4,135
1                                  Cost Of Goods Sold            $3,179
2                                        Gross Profit              $956
...
   2007-12-31 2007-09-30 2007-06-30 2007-03-31 2006-12-31 2006-09-30  \
0      $5,672     $3,262     $2,886     $3,015     $3,986     $2,307
1      $4,501     $2,500     $2,185     $2,296     $3,135     $1,758
...
   2006-06-30 2006-03-31 2005-12-31 2005-09-30 2005-06-30 2005-03-31  
0      $2,139     $2,279     $2,977     $1,858     $1,753     $1,902
1      $1,630     $1,732     $2,309     $1,395     $1,303     $1,444
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped. Is their an easy way to include the dates as well when data is extracted such as 2005-03-21 etc?

Comment: just look in the browser what element has what id  the table is under   driver.find_element_by_id('contenttablejqxgrid"'), the header is inside of 
class="jqx-widget-header jqx-grid-header" , id="columntablejqxgrid", or just find by each cells with class="jqx-grid-column-header jqx-widget-header or  role="columnheader"

Comment: i got another question : why col_id =  'columntablejqxgrid'


hdr_row = driver.find_element_by_id(col_id)

cells = hdr_row.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')

print(', ' .join(cell.text.rstrip() for cell in  cells)) 
works wrong, and i get only wisible cells and some cells doubled?

Comment: Updated in response to first comment